# Finding Switch connectivity and ATM Status

Tags: xfs, cen-xfs

Through CEN-XFS,
I am able to get the device status of all peripherals in an ATM. But, is there a standard way to find if the ATM application is connected to switch and is in-service?

Comment: @Gabe Thorns: Could you help me with this ?

Comment: No, there is no SPI interface to control application. But, application can use SIU indicators to set it's state changes. And you can ask SIU status. But you depends on how applicaton is done.